# C# Performance with collections and iterators

Tags: c#, .net, performance, oop, iterator

Can you please explain if the approach taken in example 1 differs in performance from the approach in example 2? If yes, which one is the most efficient and why.

"Performaces" i'm talking about are not only related to the execution speed. I also would like some explaination about different system resources use.

1.

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetObjectsStrings(List<object> input)
    {
        IList<string> result = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            result.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

2.

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetObjectsStrings(List<object> input)
    {
        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            yield return item.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want better performance, you might want to use an array, but I believe those are the same. Create a test suite that times the functions being executed over the same object a couple of thousand times. That'll tell you which runs faster.

Comment: [Race your horses!](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Why not simply try it out by **measuring**?

Comment: I don't want better performance, i'm not asking this for a real case scenario. Just wondering if the second method i show really avoids overhead caused, maybe, by the creation of auxiliary data structures.

Comment: I'm just searching where i asked for "speed performance". Something can be more performing that something else by just doing things "better", not just faster.

Comment: "This runs in 1 second and that in 2" isn't the answer i was looking for. I'm able to measure time by myself

Comment: I'd like to point out that this isn't C# way to do that. You should go with `return input.Select(x => x.ToString());` - this is basically equivalent  to the second case

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek Ok, but what if i don't want to use LINQ? Or i can't? C# isn't telling you you MUST use LINQ to work over collections.

Comment: @moro91 the thing is, if anyone else would to look at your code he would scratch his head why on earth would you do this this way if you CAN use LINQ? If you don't want to use it, don't, but be ready to answer questions why :P

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek I use LINQ everyday while doing my job. To make code readable and follow organization standards :) I'm asking it for personal knowledge, not job-related tasks

Comment: @moro91 so if you want raw benefits, here are some: LINQ is lazy evaluated and composable. That means you almost always get better performance than with a loop. If want eager solution, just add `.ToArray()`. And it is far more readable, maybe with some exceptions. There aren't any advantages in not using it other than personal taste

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek So, isn't the second example i wrote here, what linq really does in the background? Obviously not only this, but this to work over collections and evaluate them "lazilly"

Comment: Someone add the tag premature-optimisation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scenario 1, you're processing the entire list, then returning that list via an `IEnumerable` interface.  No matter what the caller intends to do with that returned `IEnumerable`, the entire list is processed each time `GetObjectsStrings` is called.

In scenario 2, you only process as many entries from the `input` list as are required by the caller.  So, you're creating an iterator.

Here's an example where it would make a difference:

`var temp = GetObjectsStrings(input).First();`

Scenario 1:  You process `input` completely for each such call, every time.
Scenario 2:  You only process the first item in `input`.  Then, the iteration is complete.

Comment: note, that if LINQ `Select` was used, also only 1 element would be processed

Answer (score 1):

They do different things, so there will definitely be a difference.

The first one is creating a new list that contains the `ToString` version of the items from the existing list, and then returning that new list.

The second one is iterating over an existing List, and returning the `ToString` version, without making any copies.

2 is the most efficient (in terms of speed and memory usage), because there are no new lists being make or copies of anything.

Comment: So, the only advantage in this approach is that i don't have to create objects in my method to hold a copy of data i'm processing, right?

Comment: That's not the only advantage, but I think the real question is, what are you doing?  These 2 functions are 'different'.  The output might be equivalent, but they are different.

Comment: That's exactly what i was trying to ask. I see these two functions produce the same output (given the same input, obviously). I would like some "expert" in this topic, to explain me why the second approach is memory-optimized at low level beacause i don't have the skills to find this information myself and understand it correctly.